# Como mudar o ciclo de vida do maven?

Tags: java, maven, ejb, ant

Tenho um projeto EJB e gostaria de executar o teste depois de fazer o deploy do meu ear. Pois tenho um teste na camada ejb, que precisa acessar o ejbstubs dentro do servidor(was), antes eu fazia isso com ant, mas estou mudando para o maven, mas não estou conseguindo mudar o ciclo de vida.

Comment: Por que não usar o [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/)?

Comment: Você já tentou colocar um teste simples dentro da pasta src/test/java? O ciclo de vida padrão do maven já executa os testes do Junit que estão nessa pasta quando você invoca clean install, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim, você pode configurar o plugin surefire:

```
<build>
...

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/integration/*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
     <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals> 
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>none</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <include>**/integration/*.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Fonte e mais informações: [Testes Integrados](http://edermag.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/testes-integrados-com-junit-maven-e.html)